# how to access env variable in sass?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js

could you please tell me how to access `env` variable in `scss`.Here is my code

https://repl.it/@naveennsit/DirtyAcrobaticClasslibrary

I am able to access `env` variable in `jsx` like that

`<a>About sss{process.env.customKey}</a>`

I created `env` variable like this

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    customKey: "my-value",
    red: "red",
    bg:'data:image/jpeg;base64,
```

Now I want to access `variable` in scss file.But I am getting error.

I am trying to access like this

```
// background-image: url($process.env.bg})
```

any update ?

Comment: but `nextjs` framework has provisions to add additional data .Not sure how to acheive this

Comment: in `sass-loader` i will pass `additional data` but I am not aware how to pass this things

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60058352/367865) will help.

Comment: @Ouroborus ye this is correct .I am looking that only .But issue is `nextjs` already used `sass-loader` in build I need there should be another way to send variable in `sass`

Comment: You can't access your `env` variable inside sass, you need to "allow" it.

Check this answer of mine, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63912418/access-environment-variables-from-sass-in-next-js/63914630#63914630